# How to start SymmetricDS on Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, symmetricds

I'm trying to start SymmetricDS 3..7.4 on Tomcat 8. The problem is -- I cannot figure out what to do after I've deployed war. How do I start/stop it?

When using embedded SymmetricDS server (jetty) started with command

```
bin\sym
```

when I go to the sync.url in my web-browser I can see folder structure and empty WEB-INF folder, but from tomcat on the url localhost:8080/engine_name (path to war) I only see 404. (Maybe, this is just the peculiarity of jetty vs tomcat, because corresponding .../sync/ url gives 503 in both cases).

Either way, I'd like to know, how can I control SymmetricDS after Tomcat deployment, as I couldn't find any comprehesive tutorial as if it's obvious for everybody and I for some reason just don't get it.

**Update**

Okay, I realize this sounds dumb, but more precese question:

-- Do I need to change `sync.url` and `registration url`in *.properties* files and if I do (which is probably the case), to what? `http://localhost:<tomcat-port>/<engine-name>/sync`? Or something else?

**Update 2**
I've solved my question. The sync.url shold actually be as I suspected, `http://localhost:<tomcat-port>/<engine-name>/sync`, and the SymmetricDS server starts when I start it in tomcat, no additional action is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat's logs contain information about startup of symemtricds engine. You'll have to provide the configuration properties file's location in web.xml. One instance of symmetricds is useless. There must be at least two to enable the synchronization, or two engines configured with two separate properties files. One instance with two engines can sync two databases.

It's very useful to go through the quick tutorial, too.

Comment: That's just it. I went through the tutorial, and I have tutorial's corp-000, store-001 and store-002. When I start `bin\sym`, they syncronize, but when I deploy three wars into tomcat and start them (wars) -- nothing happens

Comment: Have you configured symmetric-ds.properties file path in web.xml?

Comment: I got it, thank you. My question was how to start it, but as it happens, it starts when I start `.war` file in tomcat. I just had wrong `sync.url`s in my `.properties` file. Now that I got it, and judging by the log file output I have another problem and I think I should post another question. Thanks for your help, though!